# Delphi file types

Tags: delphi, version-control

I am looking for a list of all file types that can be associated to a Delphi project (all versions of Delphi), more specifically all file types that should be under source control.

[This site](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions) doesn't mention Delphi 2009 so I'm not sure if there may be new file types.

Is there maybe such a list directly from Codegear?

---

Putting all the answers together, here is a list:

Files -> Source Control

- .bdsgroup - Project Group
- .bdsproj  - Project
- .bpg      - Project Group
- .cfg      - Project Configuration
- .dfm      - Delphi Form
- .dof      - Project Options
- .dpk      - Package
- .dpr      - Project
- .dproj    - Project
- .pas      - Pascal File
- .res      - Resource File
- .todo     - IDE Todo

I am not sure about these: Should they be included?

- .dem
- .dro
- .local

Maybe there is anything still missing?

Comment: .res is a tricky one. They can be autogenerated (e.g. form), or not (if explicitely linked, e.g. some manifest or other resource). I don't add the autogenerated ones to my svn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to Prism:

- .pas is the source code - been that way in all versions
- .dcu delphi compiled unit (compiled .pas file)
- .dfm delphi form
- .dpr Delphi project
- .res resource file
- .dpk delphi package
- .dcp compiled version of dpk
- .dpl/.bpl Windows DLL with Delphi specifics in it
- .BPG, .BDSGROUP  Borland Project group
- .dcr compiled version of .res
- .dof settings for solution
- .dsk settings for IDE specific to the solution (i.e. what windows are open)
- .dro This text file contains information about the object repository.
- .dmt This proprietary binary file contains the shipped and user-defined menu templates information
- .tlb Type library
- .dem This text file contains some standard country-specific formats for a TMaskEdit component

From my limited work with Prism it seems

- .pas is the source code - includes forms now
- .dproj Delphi project
- .resx resource file
- .vsproj delphi package

Comment: Neither *.dcu, *.dcp nor *.dsk should go into the version control; the first two because they can easily be recreated, and the last one because it's only a minor inconvenience to not have it in a clean checkout, but it can be a major pain to have a wrong one (smaller resolution, only 1 monitor, ...)

Comment: I miss .dfn and other ITE extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Just a couple of extra ones that should not be included (at least I don't.):

- .drc - generated on every compile (list of bound resources)
- .map - map file
- .dproj.local
- .identcache
- .groupproj.local

Ones that should:

- .todo - Project todo file for IDE.
- .inc  - Delphi/Pascal Include files.

Others that depend on what your storing:

- .groupproj - Delphi group of projects file

Answer (score 4):

Here's a guide for setting up [Subversion with Delphi](http://sourceitsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/07/starting-out-with-delphi-and-subversion.html).  He uses this "Global Ignore Patterns" file filter for subversion:

I use

```
*.dcu *.~* dcu temp *.exe *.zip *.bkm *.ddp *.cfg *.dof *.dsk *.ini *.hlp *.gid 
*.bmp *.png *.gif ~* *.log bin debug release *.map *.chm *.bkf Thumbs.db *.mdb 
.obj *.elf *.stat *.ddp *.bpl *.map *.GID *.hlp *.opt *.dll *.raw *.BIN *.obj 
*.pdb *.scc Debug Release *.xml obj *.~* *.backup *.INI *.ArmLog *.KeyLog 
*.NanoLog *.Stats *.PreARM *.old *.drc *.*~ *.doc *.pdf *.bmp *.jpg *.MRW *.NEF 
*.ORF *.psd *.X3F __history *.local *.identcache *.bak Thumbs.db *.ldb *.dex 
*.rar DllDcu *.lck CVS cvs *.txt *.TXT *.jdbg *.HLP *.KWF *.xls *.cnt *.dsm 
*.dti *.tmp *.lnk *.cbk *.mes
```

Note that the patterns are case sensitive.

Comment: I don't think you're making it clear that this is the list of files to AVOID.
  
That list is introduced as, "In the Global ignore patterns, enter in the file types that should be ignored by default. Ie things like map files that will (almost) never need to be under version control. I use..."

Comment: @Wouter: I'll admit it's a useful list, but the answer is clearly wrong (as I explained in my comment), and thus upvoting makes little sense to me.  Oh, well - just my $0.02

Comment: I've edited Dave's answer to (hopefully) make it clear that this is a list of file types to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions) a **.local** file is for

> Delphi/CB 2005 onwards: User-specific project options. When using Starteam projects it will
>   contain overrides to settings from the .bdsproj file.

Answer (score 0):

The ".local" files probably SHOULD be included in version control - at least with Rad Studio 2010 (I haven't checked more recent versions).

They are XML files that include (among other cruft) the visual ordering of files in the project within each folder:-

```
<ProjectSortOrder AutoSort="0" SortType="0">
    <File Path="..\PPP\base.optset"/>
    <File Path="..\HPPP\debug.optset"/>
    <VirtualFolder ID="{BC2DCF60-71AB-4F00-AFCB-CC7FA5414FB5}"/>
    <VirtualFolder ID="{DFA8BFE5-37E7-45F6-B964-18198CB18581}"/>
    <File Path="..\PPP\Xyzzy.cpp"/>
```

If you delete the .local files, the files in the project are shown in alphabetical order rather than the order you had dragged them into. This is a handy trick to quickly get your files back into alphabetical order!